# Contents of extraResources getting included in app.asar file

Tags: electron, electron-builder

This problem only started appearing yesterday, after no code changes and has me stumped.

We have 300mbs of files being included in the build under extraResources. In the past, these files were not included in app.asar.

```
"extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "./bin",
        "to": "bin",
        "filter": [ "**/*" ]
      }
    ],
```

As of yesterday they started getting included, which meant an app.asar file that jumped in size form 9mb to 300mb+. This increases the size of the installation file from 120mb to 190mb.

I've been trying to work out how to exclude these files from app.asar but nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions?

Comment: The point of [`extraRresource`](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents.html#extraresources) is to include extra stuff. If they were not included then it was a bug. If you don't want them, then remove the option.